# Applet AccessControlException(SecurityException) - updated Java 7 update 45

Tags: java, security, applet, centos, tomcat7

Our applet application uses Java 7 update 40 before and we use to deploy it in Tomcat 7. It was working fine.

Now i have updated the Java 7 update 45 compiled using this and deployed in Tomcat 7 in CentOs linux and hitting that URL from windows. If i access that application Security Exception pop is coming.

```
AccessControlException access denied("java.util.PropertyPermission""myProp""write")
```

I search in google as well stackoverflow. I understood that some security policy have to update. I modified tomcat/conf/catalina.policy in linux

```
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

under WebApplication Permission.But no use it is exactly showing error in

```
System.getProperty("myProp");
```

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem. As well explain some thing what other security updation added in Java 7 update 45

Thanks

Comment: When you say "applet" do you mean an applet as in "java.applet"? In which case, changing the security policy on the server wont have an effect on the security policy for the client.

Comment: Yes "java.applet" from rt.jar. while i hitting the url from client (windows) this hits the linux server.error is displaying client side as pop up.I have changed the code in server/tomcat7/conf/catalina.policy.

Comment: I found the solution for this problem. I have no permission to access "myprop". So we have to give permission in java.policy file in Java_installed_path/jre/lib/security/ where we are accessing ( client side machine),

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "my prop", "write"
After adding this in java.policy under "default permissions granted to all domains" section . It is working fine.

Thanks.